# Pushing NaN in GeoJson

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, geojson, mongoose-schema

I've converted my csv file to json array and want to upload it to mongodb in geojson form here is my schema

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  INDIRIZZO: String,
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String, 
      enum: ['Point'], 
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  }

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

here is the procedure to upload it though json array

```
let json = csvToJson.formatValueByType().getJsonFromCsv('file.csv');

for (let i = 2; i < json.length; i++) {
    var post = new Post({

        INDIRIZZO: json[i].INDIRIZZO,
        location: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [
               parseFloat(json[i].LATITUDINE),
                parseFloat(json[i].LONGITUDINE),
            ]
        }
    })
    post.save();
}
```

now the problem is I've some latitude and longitude missing at some indexes of an this json array so nothing is uploading to mongodb , the error is

```
(node:10472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Post validation failed: location.coordinates: Cast to Array failed for value "[ NaN, NaN ]" at path 
"location.coordinates"
```

Thanks for your good advice in advance

Comment: Just use simply `if else` and put the coordinates as blank `[]` where `lat` and `long` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved by using this convention

```
let json = csvToJson.formatValueByType().getJsonFromCsv('file.csv');

for (let i = 2; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (!parseFloat(json[i].LATITUDINE) || !parseFloat(json[i].LONGITUDINE)) {
        var post = new Post({

            INDIRIZZO: json[i].INDIRIZZO,
            location: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: []
            }
        })
        post.save();
    } else {
        var post = new Post({

            INDIRIZZO: json[i].INDIRIZZO,
            location: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates:
                    [parseFloat(json[i].LATITUDINE),
                    parseFloat(json[i].LONGITUDINE),]
            }

        })
        post.save();
    }
}
```